# Arzela-Ascoli related problem. Proving uniform convergence of the whole sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Given a positive real number $a$, a real $\lambda > 1$ and a Lipschitz function $f:[-a,a] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0) = 0$ we define the following set of functions: $f_{k} (x) = \lambda f_{k-1}(\frac{x}{\lambda})$. By using Ascoli-Arzela theorem one can easily prove the existence of a uniformly convergent partial subsequence, but then I'm asked to prove that if $f \in C^1$, then the whole sequence is uniformly convergent to a certain function, and here's where I'm stuck.

By finding a general expression for $f_{k} (x)$ in terms of $f$ it's easy to conjecture that the limit function is $f'(0)x$, but I'm not sure how to prove the convergence is uniform. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove by induction that
$$
f_k(x) = \lambda^k f \left(\frac{x}{\lambda^k}\right).
$$
Let us fix $\epsilon > 0$.
Since $f'$ is continuous at $0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
|f'(s) - f'(0)| < \epsilon \qquad \forall |s| < \delta.
$$
Hence, if $k > -\log \delta / \log \lambda$ (i.e., if $\lambda^{-k} < \delta$) one has
$$
|f_k(x) - f'(0) x| = \lambda^k \left|\int_0^{x/ \lambda^k}f'(s)\, ds - f'(0) \frac{x}{\lambda^k}
\right|
\leq
\lambda^k \left|\int_0^{x/\lambda^k} |f'(s) - f'(0)|\, ds\right|
\leq \epsilon |x| \leq \epsilon a,
$$
so that $f_k(x) \to f'(0) x$ uniformly in $[-a, a]$.