# Pointwise Convergence Of Sequence Of Real Functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

Let $f_1:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, $f_1(0)=0$ be continuously differentiable function and $\lambda>1$. Consider the sequence of function defined by 
$f_k(x):=\lambda f_{k-1}(x/\lambda)$, $k≥2,$ , $x\in [0,1]$. Find the pointwise limit of the sequence of function.

My Approach:

By the recurring relation, we get,  $f_n(x)=\lambda^{n-1} f_1(x/\lambda)$. If we take the limit and using the continuity of $f_1$, we come across a situation of $\infty •0$. Please help me further.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2310382/42969.

Comment: Both duplicate targets were quickly found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f_k(x)%3A%3D%5Clambda%20f_%7Bk-1%7D(x%2F%5Clambda)%24&p=1)

Answer (score 1):

$f_n(x)=\lambda^{n-1} f_1(x/\lambda)$ is not correct. We have $f_n(x)=\lambda^{n-1} f_1(x/\lambda^{n-1}).$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Ooops, many thanks !

Comment: I'm getting $f_n(x)=\lambda^(n-1)f_1(x/\lambda)$.